# Passing data to javascript chart

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am having a list passed from server to jsp like this,

```
 <c:forEach items="${query}" var="u"> <p>${u.date} ${u.count}</p> </c:forEach>
```

I am taking an array in javascript to hold the query object and then passing that array to datapoints as follows,

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
var arr = new Array();
<c:forEach items="${query}" var="u" varStatus="status"> 
var cnt= '${u.count}';
if(cnt=="")
    arr.push( '{' + 'x' +  ':' + '${u.date}'+ ',' + 'y' + ':' +'0' + '}' + ',');
else
   arr.push( '{' + 'x' +  ':' + '${u.date}'+ ',' + 'y' + ':' +'${u.count}' + '}' + ',');
</c:forEach> 

var arrayLength = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    alert(' '+arr[i]);

}

       var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {

     title:{
      text: "Earthquakes - per month"
      },
       data: [
      {
        type: "line",

        dataPoints: [
      arr
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
  }

</script>
```

But the graph is not showing data passed to arr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an attribute on any of the available scopes to make the object accessible via Expression Language - and then use EL constructs wherever required in your page.
Please try this:

```
 <%
     List  query = new ArrayList();
     HashMap sampleObj = new HashMap();
     sampleObj.put("date", "2015");
     sampleObj.put("count", 145);

     query.add(sampleObj);
     query.add(sampleObj);
     query.add(sampleObj);

     pageContext.setAttribute("query",query);

     System.out.println("Len : "+query.size());

     %>

...
        <script>

        var chartObj = {
               title: {
                  text: "Earthquakes - per month"
                 },
               data: [
                      {
                       type: "line",
                       dataPoints: [

                             <c:forEach items="${query}" var="u" varStatus="statusVar">
                             <c:if test="${ statusVar.index > 0 }">
                                <c:out value="," />
                             </c:if>
                             <c:out value="{ x : ${u.date}, y:  ${u.count} }" />
                             </c:forEach>

                              ]
                     }
                 ]
             };

        alert(JSON.stringify(obj));

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", chartObj);
        chart.render();

        </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that no operations inside of dataPoints actually work. I have made editions in the javascript to create an array of data and pass it to dataPoints. But the graph is still not displayed

Comment: You need to set the object as an attribute onto the page (or session or application, if suitable) for it to be usable via the Expression Language. The above code works for me.

Comment: Where exactly to set the object as an attribute, I tried your recommendation and got the graph also, but the points this time are missing. can you please show me the full jsp page(or create a hyperlink to the page) that you have worked, It will help me a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: In <% ... %> scriptlet tags.

Comment: Yes, I did the same , like this <%
java.util.List query = new java.util.ArrayList(); 
pageContext.setAttribute("query",query);
%>

Comment: try to see the html source in browser and see if points are printed fine, or the error is in Javascript.

Comment: Are you leaving a trailing comma?